# Replaced CPU, motherboard, and memory. Black screen when booting

Tags: drivers, migration

Due to a house fire most of my Ubuntu 22.04 media server needed to be replaced.  Currently the only parts that really survived was the storage drives. So based on what I read, I was hoping that I could move everything to new hardware without needing to reinstall the OS and have to redo the configuration of the server.

The new equipment is the R5 7600X CPU and ASRock B650 PG motherboard (also new RAM and PSU).  My previous build used onboard graphics as well, so no GPU before or after.  After setting the BIOS to CSM (legacy) mode my drives were detected and I was able to seemingly boot into my system drive.  The computer reacts, the screen flashes occasionally, but all I ever see is a black screen and as far as I can tell it does not engage the network, so I cannot SSH into it.

I booted into a Live disk and confirmed that all drives are running and can be accessed.  I tried running boot-repair but that did not resolve the issue.  I assume there is a driver issue but I do not know how to install the necessary driver from Live.
If all else fails, all data is on a separate set of drives and I can access the system drive to pull any app settings, so I can recover if I need to just reinstall Ubuntu Server, but I was hoping to avoid it if possible.

Comment: New motherboard needs new install of the OS.

Comment: If BIOS install, it should just boot. If UEFI, you can use efibootmgr to add entry to UEFI on motherboard boot menu or reinstall grub. For specific help post link to Summary Report from Boot-Repair. Best if booted in mode UEFI or BIOS that your install is. And new systems are UEFI, so best to have UEFI installs on gpt partitioned drives. Vendors are now starting to make UEFI only, no CSM/Legacy/BIOS boot option.